# How to find Cell index inside kendo-grid & how to set dirty property as true

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I just want to select Check Box on Icon 'A' click. So how will I find check box control.

```
<a class="tooltip-top" onclick="GridArchiveAction(#: id #); " title="Archive" ><img src="/Content/images/Archive.png" style="cursor: pointer;"/></a>
```

**file.js**

```
var GridArchiveAction = function (id) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to archive this item?")) {
        var grid = $('#Grid').data("kendoGrid");
        var item = grid.dataSource.get(id);
        var dataRow = grid.dataSource.getByUid(item.uid);
        if (dataRow != undefined) {
            dataRow.addClass("k-state-selected")
                .find(".isLockedchkbx")
                .prop("checked", "checked");

        } else {
            alert("You Must Select A Row To Archive A Record!");
        }
    }
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why you need checkbox control?

Generally you can get it passing this like

```
onclick="GridArchiveAction(this, #: id #); "
//OR
var GridArchiveAction = function (this, id);`
```

You can get checkbox control by `$(this)`.

Comment: If you can put your code in jsfiddle and send me link, i can help you. You can set checkbox checked by $(this).prop('checked', true);

Comment: _I don't want user to select checkbox directly.. user has to click 'A' img btn to select checkbox_ so I've to find the control and then set it true on click.. i think

Comment: Then you have to set some attribute like element_id="checkbox_#: id#" to checkbox element.  So on click of 'A' icon, write $(['element_id'='checked_'+id]).prop('disabled', false);

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<body>
    <div id="grid"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
                    },
                    pageSize: 20
                },
                height: 550,
                groupable: true,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 5
                },
                columns: [{
                    template: "<a class='tooltip-top' onclick='GridArchiveAction(this);' title='Archive' ><img src='http://www.naadsm.org/naadsm/files/common/smallZipFileIcon.png' style='cursor: pointer;'/></a>",
                    field: "ContactName",
                    title: "Contact Name",
                    width: 240
                }, {
                    template: "<input class='isLockedchkbx' type='checkbox' />",
                    field: "ContactTitle",
                    title: "Contact Title"
                }]
            });
        });

        function GridArchiveAction(obj) {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to archive this item?")) {
                var grid = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid");
                var row = $(obj).closest("tr");
                $(row).find('.isLockedchkbx').prop("checked", "checked");
            }
        };

    </script>
</body>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: great..that works.. but the problem is red flag is not showing that mean its dirty property is not set as true.. then how will I save grid changes

Comment: yes.. bool property.. want to set (_as true_) on 'A' btn click ( then save thechanges)

Comment: Could you please share code. I want to see your all column's declaration.